# Storage size of ' ' isn't know

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, header, storage

I'm writing a C program. Ones of its headers declares a structure like this:

```
struct s_emulator;
```

Then I define it in a source file:

```
struct s_emulator
{
    struct s_cpu cpu;
    struct s_screen screen;
    struct s_input in;
};
```

To finally use it in my main.c file:

```
struct s_emulator emulator;
```

Everything seems okay, but I get the following error messages:

```
src/main.c:7:23: error: storage size of ‘emulator’ isn’t known
    7 |     struct s_emulator emulator;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: put the **definition** of s_emulator **before** your usage - only putting **declaration** before usage is not enough.

Comment: You define it in a different source file. That means the size of it is unknown in the context of main.c. You should just put the definition in the header.